# Is there a feature in Java Spring Cache to recalculate value assync if ttl expired?

Tags: spring, caching, asynchronous

Is there a way to configure the cache behavior like async recalculation cache if TTL? 
As a query might be too heavy - I would prefer to return a value from cache, but I also want to trigger recalculation, until the value has been recalculated - return it from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Spring provides an abstraction over existing caching libraries like [ehcache](/questions/tagged/ehcache). So you should have a look at your caching provider. For example in EhCache you can start with [`UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache.html) - but it is blocking.